# Elastic Search fails to start - Setting using Ansible

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following error when starting elastic search. The elastic search is called via ansibles:

> [2018-10-03T19:40:53,846][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [nZYtSvi]
>   starting ... [2018-10-03T19:40:53,951][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap
>   ] [nZYtSvi] Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No
>   up-and-running site-local (private) addresses found, got [name:lo
>   (lo), name:eth0 (eth0)]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkUtils.getSiteLocalAddresses(NetworkUtils.java:184)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkService.resolveInternal(NetworkService.java:246)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkService.resolveInetAddresses(NetworkService.java:220)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkService.resolveBindHostAddresses(NetworkService.java:130)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.bindServer(TcpTransport.java:732)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.doStart(Netty4Transport.java:175)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:69)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:219)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:69)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.Node.start(Node.java:694)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:278)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:351)
>   [elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]     at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:132)
>   [elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]     at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:123)
>   [elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]     at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:70)
>   [elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]     at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134)
>   [elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]     at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
>   [elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]     at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91)
>   [elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]     at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84)
>   [elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12] [2018-10-03T19:40:53,957][WARN
>   ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception
>   in thread [main] org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No up-and-running site-local
>   (private) addresses found, got [name:lo (lo), name:eth0 (eth0)]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:123)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:70)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12] Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No up-and-running site-local
>   (private) addresses found, got [name:lo (lo), name:eth0 (eth0)]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkUtils.getSiteLocalAddresses(NetworkUtils.java:184)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkService.resolveInternal(NetworkService.java:246)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkService.resolveInetAddresses(NetworkService.java:220)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkService.resolveBindHostAddresses(NetworkService.java:130)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.bindServer(TcpTransport.java:732)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.doStart(Netty4Transport.java:175)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:69)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:219)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:69)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.Node.start(Node.java:694)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:278)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:351)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:132)
>   ~[elasticsearch-5.6.12.jar:5.6.12]    ... 6 more
>   [2018-10-03T19:40:54,892][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [nZYtSvi]
>   stopping ... [2018-10-03T19:40:54,896][INFO ][o.e.n.Node
>   ] [nZYtSvi] stopped [2018-10-03T19:40:54,896][INFO ][o.e.n.Node
>   ] [nZYtSvi] closing ... [2018-10-03T19:40:54,909][INFO ][o.e.n.Node
>   ] [nZYtSvi] closed

Answer (score 1):

Try adding network.host 0.0.0.0 in the elasticsearch.yml config file